# How can I print out this array method that finds duplicates?

Tags: java, arrays

```java
package Practice3;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ray1 {

    public static int[] findDuplicates(int[] userInput)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i< userInput.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i+1; j < userInput.length; j++)
            {
                if(userInput[i]==(userInput[j]))
                {
                    System.out.println(userInput[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        return userInput;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int[] listOfNumbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1 };

        int[] x = findDuplicates(listOfNumbers);
        Arrays.sort(x);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x));
    }
}
```

I think the issue could be in the static void main, but I'm not quite sure what's wrong with the code.

Comment: Try to replace the print with System.out.println(x.toString());

Comment: Can you try to explain your question a bit more? It's not clear what you want to achieve. Perhaps give us the expected result.

Comment: what are you trying to do? Print them out while searching (which you are currently doing) or returning an array of duplicates and then printing that array. You are just returning the original array.

Comment: Sorry, I am trying to make it display [ 1, 2, 3 ] instead of all the numbers together, so it could show me what the duplicate numbers are instead of all of them. (So it wouldn't show 4 because it's only showing once in the string).

Comment: You are just printing out the original array without even trying to alter it in any way. It is not clear how you expect that to do what you say you want.

Comment: @DavidConrad sorry, I'll try to make some adjustments to it :/

Answer (score 0):

You return the input you got so of course you wont get the duplicates.
You should create a hashset in your function and add the duplicates to it.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] listOfNumbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1 };
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(findDuplicates(listOfNumbers));
        Collections.sort(list);
        System.out.println(list);
  }
  
  
      public static HashSet<Integer> findDuplicates(int[] userInput) {
        HashSet<Integer> output = new HashSet<Integer>();
        for(int i = 0; i< userInput.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i+1; j < userInput.length; j++) {
                if(userInput[i]== userInput[j]) {
                    output.add(userInput[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
```

Notice that I used return type as HashSet, it's much more appropriate as you want each duplicate to appear once and then I converted it to an ArrayList and printed it.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, both `int[] listOfNumbers` and `int[] x` are the same. You have passed `int[] listOfNumbers` into the `findDuplicates()` method, and returned the same without changing anything.

If you are trying to remove the duplicates inside that method, then you need to do something inside the loop where you check for `value[i] == value[j] where i!=j`.

One suggestion for you is to try and add the numbers into a `Collection` when `value[i] != value[j]`, but not when they are similar.

When this is done, at the end of the two loops you will have a `Collection` with unique numbers. Then you will be able to sort and print.

**Note:** This is not the simplest or the optimal way as Java has a concept called `Set` to collect unique elements. First, it is good if you can change your method and figure out how to get these two loops to cater the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest first fixing the `findDuplicates` method to do what it's supposed to do. My understanding is that it should return an array that contains the values that occur more than once in the `userInput` array.

One way to to this could be to create a new array at the beginning of the `findDuplicates` method and name it for example `duplicatedValues`. You can then fill it with the values that the rest of the method logic identifies as duplicates. Given your statement in one of your comments that the output should be `[ 1, 2, 3 ]`, I think you should also alter the `if` statement to only accept values that are not already in the `duplicatedValues` array, which might even mean a 3rd `for` loop. Otherwise, the `duplicatedValues` array will itself also contain duplicates.

When you've populated the `duplicatedValues` array with "unique duplicates", you can return that array instead of the `userInput` array.